# Remote IIS Management

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

I've got an ASP.Net application which manages the IIS server as follows:

Successfully using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager to manage the local IIS 7 server no problem (I'm creating new sites, virtual folders etc on the fly).

What I really need to do is manage a remote server to do the same.

e.g. Web Application lives on IIS01, user clicks on "Create Virtual Folder" button, and this then connects to IIS02 to create the required folder.

I'm assuming that Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager is NOT the correct way to go forward as this appears to manage the local instance only, so what is- if it's possible?

Comment: You might get better answers to your question on ServerFault.com. We're more about programming questions here.

Comment: This isn't  a ServerFault question, **it's a programming question** about the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.aspx?ppud=4) class.  This question should *not* be moved.

Comment: It is a programming question.... check out (a) Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager and (b) the c# asp.net tags

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the static [`ServerManager.OpenRemote()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote(v=VS.90).aspx) method to get/mange a remote system:

```
var manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("IIS02"); //Or, by IP "1.1.1.1"
```

This returns a [`ServerManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms614827(v=VS.90).aspx) instance for that machine.

Comment: I'm getting COMException, I'll try to figure out why

Comment: What about authentication?

Comment: re: authentication, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458410/credentials-for-servermanager-openremote

Comment: The namespace for `ServerManager` is `Microsoft.Web.Administration`