# Credentials for ServerManager.OpenRemote

Tags: security, iis-7.5, impersonation, iis-8

I'm trying to use ServerManager.OpenRemote (from Microsoft.Web.Administration) but am unable to find documentation on how to give it different credentials from the current user.  I tried SimpleImpersonation (from [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)) and it gives me the same error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException - Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine [...] failed due to the following error: 80070005 [...]."

Firewall on the remote machine is off.  UAC is disabled.

Comment: Impersonation won't work most of the time and I believe it's by design.

Answer (score 5):

You must enable the remote server for remote configuration. Microsoft.Web.Administration uses AHADMIN DCOM service, so this should be open for remote access.

First, make sure you can change AHADMIN properties:
https://serverfault.com/questions/242714/how-can-i-enable-ahadmin-properties

Then, follow these steps or use the provided script:
http://mvolo.com/connecting-to-iis-70-configuration-remotely-with-microsoftwebadministration/

Also, check you have remote access permissions for AHADMIN using dcomcnfg. See how here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176799 and here http://help.eprint.net/dcomconfig.htm